# Excluding Elements In Javascript / DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the html / css / javascript/jquery as follows, the event still fires when I click on '#bbb'.

Is there anyway to avoid this from happening?

```
<div id="aaa" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#f00;">
   <div id="bbb" style="height:25%; width:25%; background-color:#0f0; margin:0 auto;">
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#aaa').click(function(){alert('aaa clicked');});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( '#aaa' ).click(function (e) { 
    if ( e.target !== this ) { return; }
    alert( 'aaa clicked' );
});
```

`e.target` points to the DOM element at which the click event was fired. `this` points to the `#aaa` element (because it's his click handler). Therefore, this line

```
if ( e.target !== this ) { return; }
```

will terminate the click handler early if the `#aaa` element wasn't clicked directly.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qbDZy/

Comment: @maxp Note that you have to explicitly list the event object as the first argument of the click handler.

Comment: @mplungjan, i like it, but this ^ solution means I dont need to know about other elements, although I suppose I could use $(this).children()...

Comment: @mplungjan You solution is good under the conditions that (1) `#bbb` already has a click handler bound to it (to do some other stuff) and (2) `#bbb` is the only descendant element of `#aaa`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to cancel the event bubbling (event propagation)
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vCbdN/)

```
$('#aaa').click(function(){alert('aaa clicked');});
$('#bbb').click(function(event){alert('bbb clicked');  event.stopPropagation();});
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding as ***bbb*** element is nested within ***aaa*** element, you will probably have to handle click event in ***bbb*** element as well.

```
$('#aaa').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation(); alert('aaa clicked');});
$('#bbb').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation(); alert('bbb clicked');});
```

But do not forget to consider stoping event propagation or both event listener will get notified.

You can see [source code in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/pzL8s/)

Hope this helps.